# how to move to a newly added row and make the scroll disappear as the data grows in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I have a tabulator. When loading, it will be dynamically populated with data from an ajax call.
I also have a custom add button `add-new-task` which adds new row to the table.

How to move the row which has been added now automatically and make any scroll disappear by expanding the table div as the data grows?

I would also be great if the focus shifts to the cell editor on the 'Task Name' column in that newly added row.

```
var workflowTasksTable = new Tabulator("#inputWorkflowTasks", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
    movableRows:true,
    pagination: false,
    columns:[
        {rowHandle:true, formatter:"handle", headerSort:false, frozen:true, width:30, minWidth:30, download:false},
        {title:"Task ID", field:"task_id", headerSort:false, editor:false, width:50, minWidth:50, resizable:false, visible:true, download:false},
        {title:"Task Name", field:"task_name", headerSort:false, editor:"input"},
        {title:"Task Abbreviation", field:"task_abbr", headerSort:false, editor:"input"},
        {formatter: actionsBtnList, title:"Action", headerSort:false, download:false, resizable:false},
    ],
});

// Action to be taken whenever the user clicks "Add Task"
$('#add-new-task').on('click', async function(e) {
    workflowTasksTable.addRow({})
    .then((row) => {
        workflowTasksTable.scrollToRow(row.getPosition(),"center");
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. Hope this helps if anyone is looking for same.

Changing the layout from `fitColumns` to `fitDataTable` worked to adjust the table for new rows as the table grows without any scroll.

For focus to the first editable cell, `rowAdded` was helpful.

```
// Action to be triggered when a new row is added
workflowTasksTable.on("rowAdded", function(row){
    setTimeout(function(){row.getCell("task_name").edit();},200);
});
```

Without timeout, rowAdded function doesn't work as the callback is triggered before the new row is rendered I suppose and therefore no cell components exist on the row.

Another solution to make the table adjust the height as the data grows is using `fitData` layout with width specifications and a div styling:

```
var workflowTasksTable = new Tabulator("#inputWorkflowTasks", {
    index:"task_name",
    layout:"fitData",
    movableRows:true,
    pagination: false,
    columns:[
        {rowHandle:true, formatter:"handle", headerSort:false, frozen:true, width:30, minWidth:30, download:false},
        {title:"Task ID", field:"task_id", headerSort:false, editor:false, resizable:false, visible:false, download:false, htmlOutput:false},
        {title:"Task Name", field:"task_name", headerSort:false, editor:"input", validator:["required", "unique"], width:350, minWidth:100},
        {title:"Task Abbreviation", field:"task_abbr", headerSort:false, editor:"input", validator:["required", "unique", "maxLength:3"], width:206, minWidth:50},
        {formatter: actionsBtnList, title:"Action", headerSort:false, download:false, resizable:false, width:100},
    ],
    validationMode:"manual"
});
```

```
<div id="inputWorkflowTasks" aria-describedby="workflowTasksHelp" style="min-height: 100px;overflow: hidden;"></div>
```